# Step to step guide how to use 32bit version of Java in Eclipse

Tags: macos, java, eclipse, 32-bit

I have a Java project in Eclipse that requires Java 7 running in 32 bit mode. I tried to force running in 32 bit mode by adding the flag `-d32` to the VM arguments.

However, I then get the following message:

```
Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version.
```

I tried the same with Java 6, and there the flag works. So I supposed that I don't have a 32 bit version of Java installed. I checked all installed versions of java with `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` and get the following list:

```
1.7.0_75, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home
1.7.0_67, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, i386:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I then run the same command with the -d32 flag to check for 32 bit VMs and get the following list:

```
1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, i386:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

So it really seems that there is no Java 7 with is compatible to run in 32bit mode available on my system. I checked the Internet, but couldn't find a way how to install 32 bit Java on a Mac. It always is assumed that the -d32 switch is working. My Mac is running Yosemite (10.10.2).

So what am I doing wrong? Is there a step for step tutorial that I can follow to run my application in Eclipse in 32bit mode with Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Oracle 32 bit Java 7 for OS X. The possible OSs are listed [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and OS X just has the one entry

> Mac OS X x64  185.86 MB   jdk-7u75-macosx-x64.dmg

As Yosemite is a 64 bit OS what exactly needs to be 32 bit?

Comment: A third party library needs to be 32bit.

Comment: So can't br used with Java - get the provider to give you a 64 bit library or write a wrapper in e.g. C and run as a separate process communication via some form of IPC

Comment: Or they OpenJDK as per this question